# Develop whole Zope&Plone app in git (decentralised and without ZMI)

Tags: python, git, plone, zope, zodb

We have few Zope&Plone projects in our company and until today I was only one single developer developing all changes throught ZMI or ZopeEdit. Our company is growing so I need to start cooperating with others developers which can help me with developing features and solving bugs in projects. This means that is no more possible to use ZMI but every developer needs to make and test own changes  without affecting others work and paste own changes to production enviroment using git merge in git repo.

I need to move development to git - this means I need to start tracking all portals files and settings in git.

I think I need to move whole projects from ZODB/ZMI (including templates, scripts, sql methods, properties as portal_properties or portal_javascripts etc.) to filesystem and run git on this file system. In the next step every developer can install own pure Plone instance, pull source code and settings from git, create own branch, make changes, test, commit, push, code review ...

My question is: Is there any way to do this and start well-known rapid development process using git? Supports ZODB something like "live migration" of content/settings to/from filesystem? Is there any way to tel Zope to load some folder with content/settings from filesystem instead only from ZODB?

I know there is something called eggs, but is possible to move all types of files mentioned above to separated egg?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The way your company was following until now was the "Old Way Way" of Plone development, but this was a deprecated and discouraged way to do.

Nowadays ZMI can still be used for "quick and dirty" fixes, but commonly this changes stored in DB must be removed (and moved to real code) as soon as possible. This was already possible on Plone 2.0!
More important: every new Plone release tend to reduce the ZMI powers (for example: until Plone 2.1 you were able to do *lot* of stuff from ZMI, starting from Plone 2.5 some UI elements where impossible to be modified TTW).

So: the answer to your question is "yes". Plone can (must) read code from filesystem, and this code can be stored on VCS (it can be git svn, ...).

All of those information can be found in the [Plone Developer Manual](http://docs.plone.org/develop/index.html).

- Creating a new Plone package for modern Plone? Use [mr.bob](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/bobtemplates.plone/README.html).
- Automatically integrate VCS in your buildout? Use mr.developer

If you are starting today from a project you where developing through ZMI you must probably mode code from ZMI to filesystem.
This can be done manually; it's simpler as you are using Zope External Editor.

There is also a very old add-on ([Plone Skin Dump](https://plone.org/products/plone-skin-dump/releases)) for flushing skin content to filesystem, but I fear it won't work on recent Plone, thus it was not supporting some stuff like SQL methods (if you are using them).

Comment: What's the easiest and suggested way to achieve manual migration of the content from inside ZODB (tree-structured page templates, SQL methods, py scripts - everything linked together)? We'd like to avoid registering of big bunch of views. The best would be to keep the structure of the content, otherwise big code changes would be necessary.

Comment: Try Plone Skin Dump I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://docs.plone.org/develop/
There you can find how to create a package (egg). Its source code can be added to git. You can checkout your git repository using mr.developer during buildout. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer/

Comment: I know eggs for developing features in python, but how can I move templates, sql methods and permissions from ZMI to egg?

For example: I have template index_html in folder structure /training/test/check/ which using sql method in /sql/training_check. How can I move this files to egg and still be available to use sql methods in template and show template when call specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mr.bob](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bobtemplates.plone) to create a PloneAddon. For MySQL you can use [MySQL Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.3). Add this Packages to your Buildout in the eggs section.
Then you can write your own MySQL Statements in the Addon. I know reimplementation is expensive, but you have more control in the future.